# Could depicted items (brooch, urn, key) really be 3000 years old?

Tags: identification, archaeology

My father, who died a few years ago, has left the depicted items to me. Apparently he found them as fragments near a local hill. He had the items dated by some authority and according to that source they apparently are from 1000 BC and in the [Illyrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illyrians) tradition. They are said to be a brooch, an [urn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urnfield_culture), and part of a [key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_%28lock%29#History_of_locks_and_keys) (depicted from left to right).

[image: brooch, urn, and key]

I'd be curious how you would go about re-dating such items without too much effort or trouble? Could the items really be that old (but then, all the natural stones close to the spot where they appeared are much older :) and belong to the indicated time and culture? I can say a bit more about location, etc., later but I'd like to hear some clean-slate opinions first.

Comment: Well, it's not good enough to post as an answer, but it's entirely possible that they are as old as you've been told. It might be worth contacting a university that is well thought of for teaching archaeology (e.g University College London http://www.ucl.ac.uk/contact-list/) and asking - it may be that sending some photos will allow them to date them reasonably well.

Comment: We will need a better photo of the items - the pattern on the "brooch", and any patterns on the "urn." The key is likely medeval or modern, tho... the ancients did not have similar keys, and likely did not have metal locks at all prior to the Romans.

Comment: @RISwampYankee Thx for your comment. Will provide a better photo when there is a convenient occasion. (The items are currently on loan to a local museum.)

Comment: @Drux. Any update on this? You mentioned you could "say a bit more about location, etc"

Comment: Encourage @riswampyankee to post as answer.